# How to read a property `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` from ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, vb.net

I am trying to read **Expiration time of administrator password** from `ActiveDirectory`:

```
Dim DC = New  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Dim cmp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DC, hostnm)
Dim desting As String = cmp.DistinguishedName
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & desting)
pwdexp = de.Properties("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime").Value.ToString()
```

But what I see is just `<COM Type>`:
[image]

However, *expiration time of administrator password* can be easily read by **PowerShell**:

```
$TestValue = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx"
$TestValue.ConvertLargeIntegerToInt64($Testvalue."ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"[0])
```

And I know that there is a such property:
[image]

Interestingly, but I can read another parameter `ms-Mcs-AdmPwd`:

```
Dim DC = New  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Dim cmp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DC, hostnm)
Dim desting As String = cmp.DistinguishedName
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & desting)
pwdexp = de.Properties("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime").Value.ToString()
```

and value can be seen from debugger:

[image]

How to read a property `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` correctly?

Comment: FYI... You might look over the simple command `net user /domain administrator` just like that and then see the value for the field ***Password Expires***.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in powershell:

```
$comp = Get-ADComputer Laptop8 -Properties ms-MCS-AdmPwdExpirationTime
$([datetime]::FromFileTime([convert]::ToInt64($comp.'ms-MCS-AdmPwdExpirationTime',10)))
```

good luck
Sem

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rlmueller.net/Integer8Attributes.htm

> Many attributes in Active Directory have a data type (syntax) called Integer8. These 64-bit numbers (8 bytes) often represent time in 100-nanosecond intervals. If the Integer8 attribute is a date, the value represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 12:00 AM January 1, 1601. Any leap seconds are ignored.
>
> In .NET Framework (and PowerShell) these 100-nanosecond intervals are
> called ticks, equal to one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000
> ticks per millisecond. In addition, .NET Framework and PowerShell
> DateTime values represent dates as the number of ticks since 12:00 AM
> January 1, 0001.
>
> ADSI automatically employs the IADsLargeInteger interface to deal with
> these 64-bit numbers. This interface has two property methods,
> HighPart and LowPart, which break the number up into two 32-bit
> numbers. The HighPart and LowPart property methods return values
> between -2^31 and 2^31 - 1. The standard method of handling these
> attributes is demonstrated by this VBScript program to retrieve the
> domain lockoutDuration value in minutes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
cls;$error.clear()

$computer = Read-host "Enter the name of the computer"

$LocalAdmin = "" | Select Computer,AdmPwd,Expires

$LocalAdmin.Computer = $Computer

$LocalAdmin.AdmPwd = $(Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties ms-MCS-AdmPwd | select -ExpandProperty ms-MCS-AdmPwd)

$FileTime = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties ms-MCS-AdmPwdExpirationTime

$LocalAdmin.Expires  = $([datetime]::FromFileTime([convert]::ToInt64($FileTime.'ms-MCS-AdmPwdExpirationTime',10)))


$LocalAdmin | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Please note that the question was about VB solution. PowerShell solution was already known in original question.